# Why were Romulans "impressed and seemingly confused" by Humans?

Tags: star-trek, romulan

In the Memory Alpha article, [Romulan](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Romulan), under Section 2.1 *[External Affairs: First Contact](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Romulan#First_contact)*, it says,

> Romulans were aware of Humanity for some time before Earth knew of them. Infiltrating the highest levels of the Vulcan High Command, the Romulans were impressed and seemingly confused by Humans.

Why were Romulans "impressed and seemingly confused by Humans"? It is understood that Vulcans were somewhat of that reaction due to Humans having had a similar history and having been seen, by some at least, as a possible solution to balancing rationality with emotion. But why Romulans? After all, they wouldn't have the same respect since they never valued logic like Vulcans did.

Comment: Unless it is a direct quote from something, you might try asking whomever wrote that sentence into the wiki.

Comment: Good point. Many thanks.

Comment: This passage (without the "seemingly") has been added to Memory Alpha in 2005, with no sources: https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Romulan?diff=169044&oldid=169025